# how to dynamically add the options(options are in form of"java.sql.ResultSet") to the select tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to add the options to my select tag which I retrieved from the data base.
For example
If the user wants the location of certain store.
First the database will retrieve the "country" and displayed in select tag.
Now on selecting the country the next state's should be displayed in select tag which is retrieved from database depending upon the country that was selected.

Comment: This cannot be using JSP alone. You will have to use javascript and AJAX.

Comment: Just now I read the difference between ajax and js.http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1332116   Can u post me the link of any ajax tutorial who to refresh a particular part of html page.

Answer (score 0):

JSPs are compiled on server side. What you are trying to accomplish is DOM manipulation which happens at client side. You cannot dynamically generate state names based on country selected using JSP tags. You have to do it using javascript and Ajax. Check out [jQuery Autocomplete with remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)

I would rather post some code.

HTML

```
    <select id="PIA" name="PIA"  tabindex="2" class='combobox' required='required' placeholder="Select Office">

                    <option value="!valid">Select Office</option>    
                    <option value='AHD'>AHEMDABAD</option>    
                    <option value='BPL'>BHOPAL</option>    
                    <option value='BHU'>BHUBNESWAR</option>    
                    <option value='COC'>COCHIN</option>    
                    <option value='DLH'>DELHI</option>    
                    <option value='GZB'>GHAZIABAD</option>    
                    <option value='GUW'>GUWAHATI</option>    
                    <option value='HYD'>HYDERABAD</option>    
                    <option value='JPR'>JAIPUR</option>    
                    <option value='JAL'>JALANDHAR</option>    
                    <option value='JMU'>JAMMU</option>
                    <option value='CAL'>KOLKATA</option>
                    <option value='KOZ'>KOZHIKODE</option>    
                    <option value='LKO'>LUCKNOW</option>   
                    <option value='BOM'>MUMBAI</option>    
                    <option value='PAT'>PATNA</option>    
                    <option value='SUR'>SURAT</option>    
                    <option value='ASR'>AMRITSAR</option>    
                    <option value='BLY'>BAREILLY</option>    
                    <option value='DDN'>DEHRADUN</option>    
                    <option value='MLP'>MALAPPURAM</option>
                    <option value='NGP'>NAGPUR</option>    
                    <option value='GOA'>PANAJI</option>    
                    <option value='PNE'>PUNE</option>    
                    <option value='RPR'>RAIPUR</option>    
                    <option value='RCH'>RANCHI</option>    
                    <option value='SML'>SHIMLA</option>    
                    <option value='SGR'>SRINAGAR</option>    
                    <option value='THN'>THANE</option>    
                    <option value='TVM'>TRIVANDRUM</option>    
                  </select>

    </td>



    <!--  District -->

    <td><div class="ui-widget" id='distPop'>

    <select id='district' name='district' tabindex="2" class='combobox'>  

        <option id="!valid" value='!valid'>Select District</option> 

    </select> 
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#PIA').combobox({
    maxheight: '100px',
    selected: function(e,u){
            $.getJson({
                "yourURL",
                $(this).val();
                function(districts){
                   $.each(districts[$(this).val()], function(key, value){
               $('#district').append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+
                        "</option>");
                });

            });
      });
});
```

Don't forget to include jquery and jquery UI scripts on top of your page.

Comment: can u post some example links??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlRequest;

function changeCities() { 

xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xmlRequest.open("get", "CityServlet?stateId=2", true); 

xmlRequest.send(null); 

xmlRequest.onReadyStateChange = processResponse; 

} 

function processResponse() { 

alert(1); 

if(xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) { 

alert(xmlRequest.responseText); 

var response = xmlRequest.responseText; 

document.getElementById("res").value = response; 

} 

} 
</script> 

<body>

<form action="post" name="customerRegForm"> 

    <select name="state" onchange="changeCities()"> 

      <option value="1">Gujarat</option> 

      <option value="2">Rajasthan</option> 

   </select> 
  <select name="cities">  </select> 

  <input type="text" name="res"></input> 

</form> 

   </body>
```

Write a Servlet which accepts parameter passed from `XMLHttpRequest` and return the response from servlet.